# How can I remove unwanted spaces from txt file

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify my txt file what I'm using in dokuwiki.

I generate timestamp on top of the txt file like this:

```
function filecont($file,$data)
{
    $fileContents = file($file);

    array_shift($fileContents);
    array_unshift($fileContents, $data);

    $newContent = implode("\n", $fileContents);

    $fp = fopen($file, "w+");   
    fputs($fp, $newContent);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

And my original txt file looks like this:

Now when I use my function:

```
$txt= "Last generated: " . date("Y M D h:i:s");
filecont($file,$txt);
```

I get a result like this:

Now I don't want to remove my `====== Open IoT book ======`, it's probably because I don't have empty space in the first line?

But the worst problem that I have Is that is generates many empty spaces what I don't want.

**I only want to get `last generated` at the top of the txt file and anything else untouched**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and removed the extra newlines by changing the line:

```
$fileContents = file($file);
```

to

```
$fileContents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Adding the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag stops a newline being added to each element/line.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php.

I also removed the array_unshift(), which leaves '====== Open IoT book ======' in the file.

So my final function looked like this:

```
function filecont($file,$data)
{
    $fileContents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    //array_shift($fileContents); Removed to preserve '====== Open IoT book ======' line.
    array_unshift($fileContents, $data);

    $newContent = implode("\n", $fileContents);

    $fp = fopen($file, "w+"); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. PS I diden't even know there was a FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES lol

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Might just delete this line

```
array_shift($fileContents);
```

solve your problem?

Comment: I tried it before, but I got syntax error! Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

when you get elements of file you need to check whether `Last generated:` is as your first row or not accordong to it yu need to use `array_shift`

```
$fileContents = file($file);
  if(stripos($fileContents[0],"Last generated:") !== false)
  {
    array_shift($fileContents); //if found use shift
  }

    array_unshift($fileContents, $data);
```